# O que há de errado com Processamento de Sinais?

Tags: debate, escopo-do-site

Na votação do que é *on-topic* o assunto [Processamento de sinais](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275/101) foi razoavelmente bem votado mas tem uma quantidade grande de votos negativos. Seriam estes votos por não haver entendimento do que é o assunto? Talvez o pessoal ache que é eletrônica.

Não parece haver muita demanda para este tipo de pergunta. O que dá um pouco de medo se haverá oferta de respostas. Em algum momento talvez tenhamos que definir que algo é *off-topic* porque ela não consegue respostas. Isso pode acontecer com outros assuntos, como o Code Golf, por exemplo. Se pode obter respostas e vai ter poucas perguntas deste tipo, parece que não vai afetar o funcionamento do site. Não vamos nos transformar em um site que trata de processamento de sinais fundamentalmente. Havia o risco de algumas perguntas (não acho que fosse o caso deste tipo) fossem feitas em exagero no começo que poderia passar a impressão errada do que era o site. Acho que passamos desta fase.

Mas por enquanto, será que podemos aceitar o assunto? Quem conhece bem o assunto poderia esclarecer mais sobre o assunto e tentar reverter os votos negativos ou pelo menos conseguir mais positivos.

A votação mostra que há quase um empate no interesse. Quando há casos assim, talvez seja melhor atender, mesmo que temporariamente, os que estão interessados (se é que eles realmente existem).

Comment: Eu não votei nesse tópico justamente pq eu não sei exatamente do que se trata. Será que essa discussão é pertinente? Tivemos alguma pergunta de DSP até hoje? Não seria o caso de esperar aparecer uma e daí ver como as coisas acontecem? Talvez alguém interessado no assunto poderia dar um exemplo ou simplesmente chegar e criar uma pergunta de exemplo para vermos como que é.

Comment: A pergunta tem um objetivo até mais amplo. Estou vendo o que acontece. Acho que alguns assuntos que estão equilibrados precisam ser discutidos com mais detalhes do que a simples votação (eu não sei bem porque alguns assunto deveriam ser aceitos ou porque eles seriam problemas para nós, gostaria de saber); ou precisam ser aceitos porque tem apoiadores suficientes, mesmo que tenha algumas pessoas contrárias. Acho que só os assuntos que tem quase exclusivamente usuários contrários é que devem ser *off-topic*. Lembrando que algo pode ser mudado depois se houver necessidade.

Comment: @Math Para mim também não é muito claro (por isso mesmo eu postei aquele item pra votação), mas acho que esta pergunta se encaixa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11194/similaridade-musical-a-partir-de-padroes-de-descritores-de-mpeg-7

Comment: @bfavaretto bom exemplo, fiquei surpreso com alguém ter respondido. Acho pertinente, apesar de talvez não termos muito público para isso.

Comment: Eu tinha uma opinião equivocada que já reverti lá. A resposta do MPEG-7 é fenomenal, *game changer*, que sorte ter um analista de áudio nas fileiras do SOPT!

Comment: O que é *on-topic* ou *off-topic* também se vai vendo bigown, claro que não pode ser só uma questão de votos. Essa pergunta é um bom exemplo que o assunto é *on-topic*.

Answer (score 6):

Segundo meu parco conhecimento do assunto em questão, a pergunta **[Similaridade musical a partir de padrões de descritores de MPEG-7](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11194/similaridade-musical-a-partir-de-padroes-de-descritores-de-mpeg-7)** seria um exemplo. Ela tem uma resposta – melhor ainda, uma boa resposta.

Tanto a pergunta quanto a resposta estão bem votadas, o que é um ótimo sinal. No meta, neste momento, já não há mais um empate na votação, ela está pendendo para a aprovação com `+13/-8`.

> Quando há casos assim, talvez seja melhor atender, mesmo que temporariamente, os que estão interessados (se é que eles realmente existem).

Concordo. Neste momento não vejo nenhum motivo para deixar perguntas sobre processamento de sinais de fora do site.